# How to use Left Join with second select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query 1 in my app. However, I'm facing a performance issue with `NOT IN` (too slow). So, I'm trying to replace it with a `LEFT JOIN`. How do I write the query? and Is there any better option?

Query 1 =

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM Payment 
WHERE gl_posting LIKE :glposting 
  AND id NOT IN (SELECT PAYMENT_ID 
                 FROM UNPOST_REQUEST_P 
                 WHERE status NOT LIKE :status );
```

I tried

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM Payment 
WHERE gl_posting LIKE :glposting 
  AND id LEFT JOIN (SELECT PAYMENT_ID 
                    FROM UNPOST_REQUEST_P 
                    WHERE status NOT LIKE :status );
```

But, I get an error

> [42000][920] ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Answer (score 0):

Try with `not exists` to improve performance

```
select 
    count(id) 
FROM Payment p
where gl_posting like :glposting 
and not exists (
    select 
        payment_id
    from UNPOST_REQUEST_P ur
    where p.id = ur.payment_id
    and status not like :status
)
```

Also you should first learn how to use [left join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) (or any join).

Comment: Thank you for the answers. However, both of the queries return different results compare to the original query. These 2 return ```56235``` while original return ```56227```

Comment: @anggor try now. let me know if it still won't work.

Comment: Sir, error pops up. ```column ambiguously defined on line 2 ```. When I use ```p.id``` it returns 0

Comment: why are not using `not exists`?

Comment: ```not exist``` also produce ```56235``` while the original produce ```56227```. I try to get the same result but with better performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Query 1 = 
select count(p.id) as id
FROM Payment p
LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT payment_id
         FROM UNPOST_REQUEST_P
         WHERE status NOT LIKE :status
) urp
    ON p.id = urp.payment_id
    AND p.gl_posting like :glposting
WHERE urp.payment_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: This is oracle db. Yes, it is variable. This is exactly how I use in code.

Comment: I am not really sure if the left join will give you better performance, but you can give it a try.. You may want to check the variable values to make the LIKE operation more efficient.. The slowness you are experiencing could also be because of this operation..